# What is the WPF control that VS2010 uses for the code editor?

Tags: wpf, editor

What is the WPF control that VS2010 uses for the code editor? Some time in the past, I tried to use the 1st WPF version but it performed very bad. Seams like the performance in the .NET 4 is far better.

My question is actually related with the fact that I'm very unhappy with the editors  available for Windows and want to try made one by myself :) Any help will be very welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS2010 uses something Microsoft wrote for their own, internal use.  It is not a redistributable control.

The best code editing control for WPF I've found (to date) is [Actipro's SyntaxEditor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx).

Comment: It should be noted that it's not quite "for internal use" - if you build your application on top of VS (e.g. using VS Shell), then you can use VS editor anywhere - for any code running within VS, editor is essentially just a hostable WPF control with public and documented API.

Comment: True.  If you want to build your application around Visual Studio itself, you can.  It's not a simple, reusable WPF control, though - wrapping this into your app is a much more involved process.

Comment: Yeh, I'm sure that the Editor is an internal component. But it is not based on any existent control, for example, RichTextBox? My point is not start from scratch (Control base class).